# flink demo wordcount can not run successfully

Tags: apache-flink

just like the title decribe,
I have start flink locally in my mac

but I can't open localhost:8081 website to see the flink status.

and when I run the wordCount example just like the official website said.

it prints some error. can anyone help me give some suggestions.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute job 'Fraud Detection'.
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:302)
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
   at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149)
   at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:699)
   at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:232)
   at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:916)
   at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:992)
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
   at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:992)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'Fraud Detection'.
   at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1823)
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:128)
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:76)
   at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1699)
   at spendreport.FraudDetectionJob.main(FraudDetectionJob.java:48)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:288)
   ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
   at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$7(RestClusterClient.java:366)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:884)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:866)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:305)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:302)
   ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: Response was neither of the expected type([simple type, class org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.job.JobSubmitResponseBody]) nor an error.
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:925)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:967)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940)
   ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: Response was neither of the expected type([simple type, class org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.job.JobSubmitResponseBody]) nor an error.
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:399)
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:374)
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:966)
   ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.job.JobSubmitResponseBody` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (404)
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1429)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1059)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromInt(ValueInstantiator.java:262)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromInt(StdValueInstantiator.java:356)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromNumber(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1324)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:173)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4173)
   at org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2536)
   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:382)
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Could you share the Flink logs with us? Moreover, please make sure that the client version is the same version as the cluster version of Flink.

Answer (score 2):

You should run `bin/start-cluster.sh` to start Flink cluster before submit any job.